# Conditional matching complex regex in capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, match, capturing-group

I am writing a regex for my git `commit-msg` hook and can't deal with the last part.

This is my regex

```
/^GRP\-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE){1}\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER){1}\s-\s.+/
```

My commit messages can have 2 variations.

1. GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - (jest.config.js) : Fix testMatch option issue
2. GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue

My current regex works well with both as it completes the check after `-`.
So basically after the dash, it doesn't take care of checking the format.

I want it to check these 2 conditions and match them respectively.

- If after the dash it meets `(` then continue with that pattern and do all the checks

> Check if the opening and closing brackets are there and after the
> closing bracket it has a space and `:` and again space and the rest of
> the commit description.It should match the 1st pattern.

- If it meets an Alphanumeric character after the `-` then it matches the 2nd pattern

I have tried to use a `disjunction` in a capturing group but somehow it fails. Actually, I am guessing why it is failing as the second condition can always cover everything.

```
/^GRP\-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE){1}\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER){1}\s-\s(\(.+\)\s:\s.+|.+)/
```

**UPDATED**

These commit message patterns are invalid and shouldn't pass

- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change)
- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some description
- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (
- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - ()
- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change
- GRP-0988 FIX CORE - Some change)

Comment: Perhaps the messages here will help you: https://regex101.com/r/jVmkaS/1

Comment: Try it like this `^GRP-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\([^()]*\)\s:\s.*` See https://regex101.com/r/xOC24Y/1

Comment: It doesn't match the 2nd pattern.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Then you can make that part optional, see https://regex101.com/r/NVWCYd/1

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan About that last invalid case `GRP-0988 FIX CORE - Some change)`, it looks to me the same as `GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue`. By what criteria do you consider this case invalid?

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan … The OP might have a look into another, late provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex after the dash: `(?:(\(.*?\))(?:\s:\s))?(?!\(.*?\)(?:\s-\s)?)(.+)`

- `(?:(\(.*?\))(?:\s:\s))?` - Optionally match the previous two parts, without capturing

  - `(\(.*?\))` - Match and capture the part within parentheses. Use the non-greedy quantifier `*?` to prevent leaking into the rest of the string if there is another `)` after the part you want to match.
  - `(?:\s:\s)` - Match and discard the colon and surrounding spaces
- `(?!\(.*?\)(?:\s-\s)?)` -  Negative lookahead to ensure it does not match messages such as `(Some change)` and `(Some change) - Some description`

  - `\(.*?\)` - Match stuff within parentheses
  - `(?:\s-\s)?` - Optionally match a colon surrounded by spaces
- `(.+)` - Match and capture the rest the commit message

```js
let formats = [
  "GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - (jest.config.js) : Fix testMatch option issue",
  "GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue",
  "GRP-0900 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some change. If there are (Some text)",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change)",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some description",
]

let regex = /^GRP\-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?:(\(.*?\))(?:\s:\s))?(?!\(.*?\)(?:\s-\s)?)(.+)/

for (let format of formats) {
  console.log(format.match(regex))
}
```

Comment: Check the updated version of the post. Your regex passes for invalid message patterns. I have added those that are accepted as invalid patterns.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan Updated the regex to handle these new cases.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan There is another slight issue where the regex captures groups within the negative lookahead. I'll be fixing it soon.

Comment: Nevermind seems I had already fixed that issue. By the way, if this logic needs to be maintainable, it might be a good idea to use some if statements to get rid of the special cases instead of cramming it all into a regex.

Comment: I have added another update. Your regex is almost complete but it still passes a few invalid cases.Agree with you that I need to separate the logic and not include anything in one regex as it's a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
^GRP-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:\([^()]*\)\s:\s)?[^()]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `GRP-[0-9]+\s` Match `GRP-` 1+ digits and a whitespace char
- `(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)` Capture one of the alternatives in group 1
- `\s` Match a single whitespace char
- `(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)` Capture one of the alternatives in group 2
- `\s-\s` Match `-` between 2 whitespace chars
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert an alphanumeric to the right
- `(?:\([^()]*\)\s:\s)?` Optionally match `(...)` followed by `:`
- `[^()]*` Match optional chars other than `(` or `)`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiMgg6/1)

```js
const regex = /^GRP-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:\([^()]*\)\s:\s)?[^()]*$/;
[
  "GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - (jest.config.js) : Fix testMatch option issue",
  "GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change)",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some description",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - ()",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change",
  "GRP-0988 FIX CORE - Some change)"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${regex.test(s)} ---> ${s}`)
)
```

Comment: It shouldn't match `GRP-0900 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some change`.
If there are `(Some text)` then only ` : ` should follow it.

Comment: I have updated the post for invalid patterns.

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan I have updated the pattern for the new strings.

Answer (score 0):

Both `{1}`-[quantifiers](https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers), each following a [grouped](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) alternation, are not necessary at all.

And as for the only 2 patterns ... either `(<fileName>) : <fileChangeMessage>` or `<changeMessage>` which are allowed to follow the OP's opening sequence of ... `GRP-<version> <type> <target> -`  ... one has to precisely target this [alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) which ...

- ... either is a parentheses-free character sequence enclosed by parentheses followed by an whitespace enclosed colon followed by at least another character ... `(\(.*\)\s\:\s.{1,})`...
- ... or is a parentheses-free character sequence all to the end of the line ... `([^()]+$)`.

Therefore something like [`^GRP ... \s-\s((\(.*\)\s\:\s.{1,})|([^()]+$))/`](https://regex101.com/r/KxxCHl/1) is well suited for [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)ing only the allowed lines from the examples provided by the OP, which are ...

```txt
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change)
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some description
GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - (jest.config.js) : Fix testMatch option issue
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - ()
GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - Some change)
```

The above linked shortened regex in its entirety looks like this ...

```js
/^GRP-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s((\(.*\)\s\:\s.{1,})|([^()]+$))/gm
```

... and in case one wants to also capture the above named data in detail, one could make use of [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups), as well as of [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping, all based on the following pattern ... [`^GRP-(?<version>[0-9]+)\s(?<type>...)\s(?<target>...)\s-\s(?:(?:(?<file>\(.*\))\s\:\s(?<fileChangeMessage>.{1,}))|(?<changeMessage>[^()]+$))`](https://regex101.com/r/KxxCHl/3).

The above linked shortened regex in its entirety looks like this ...

```js
/^GRP-(?<version>[0-9]+)\s(?<type>FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(?<target>CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?:(?:(?<file>\(.*\))\s\:\s(?<fileChangeMessage>.{1,}))|(?<changeMessage>[^()]+$))/gm
```

Both regular expression placed into some example code then leads to ...

```js
const multilineSampleData =
`GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change)
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change) - Some description
GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - (jest.config.js) : Fix testMatch option issue
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - ()
GRP-0888 FIX OTHER - Fix testMatch option issue
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - (Some change
GRP-0988 FIX CORE - Some change)`;

const regXMatch =
  /^GRP-[0-9]+\s(FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s((\(.*\)\s\:\s.{1,})|([^()]+$))/gm;

const regXNamedGroups =
  /^GRP-(?<version>[0-9]+)\s(?<type>FIX|CHANGE|HOTFIX|FEATURE)\s(?<target>CORE|SHARED|ADM|CSR|BUS|OTHER)\s-\s(?:(?:(?<file>\(.*\))\s\:\s(?<fileChangeMessage>.{1,}))|(?<changeMessage>[^()]+$))/gm;

console.log(
  'multiline sample data (just two expected matches) ...\n',
  multilineSampleData
);
console.log(
  'matching lines only ...',
  multilineSampleData
    .match(regXMatch)
);
console.log(
  'existing group properties only of each matching line ...',
  [
    ...multilineSampleData
      .matchAll(regXNamedGroups)
  ]
  .map(({ groups: { file, fileChangeMessage, changeMessage, ...rest } }) => ({
      ...rest,
      ...(file && { file, fileChangeMessage } || { changeMessage }),
    }))    
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan … The OP might have a look into the above, late provided answer.